# Error 500 caused by web.config on IIS Server

Tags: php, iis, web-config

I'm experiencing problems with a web.config file I put on a /admin dir on IIS Server. Note that I'm not familiar with this kind of file, I usually use .htaccess on Apashe server.

When uploaded, the files are marked as **500 - Internal server error**. They work just fine with the un-rewritten url when I take the web.config file off of the directory /admin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rule 1H" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^modifier-(.*)$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php?page=modif-ville&id=$1"  />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 2H" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^modif-(.*)$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php?page=modif-ville&id=$1&action=modif"  />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 3H" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^inscriptions$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php?page=liste-inscrits"  />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 4H" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^inscriptions-del-(.*)$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php?page=liste-inscrits&del=$1"  />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 5H" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^inscriptions-modif-(.*)$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php?page=liste-inscrits&modif=$1"  />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 6H" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^inscriptions-valid-(.*)-set-(.*)$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php?page=liste-inscrits&valid=$1&set=$2"  />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 7H" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^inscriptions-tri-(.*)$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php?page=liste-inscrits&tri=$1"  />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can you see something wrong in that file ?

**EDIT :** 
After a few tests, it seems the problem comes with this kind of rule with an unknown variable : (.*)

When I keep only this rule, there's no problem :

```
<rule name="rule 3H" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^inscriptions$"  />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="//admin/index.php?page=liste-inscrits"  />
</rule>
```

Is there a special format for unknown variables ?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Nothing appears in the logs. I just get this error on the page : **500 - Internal server error.There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

It doesn't show up when the web.config is out of the folder.

Comment: I found something interesting (see edited post)

Answer (score 0):

I found that instead of `$1` and `$2`, you should be using `{R:1}` and `{R:2}`, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

```
<rule name="rule 1H" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^modifier-(.*)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php?page=modif-ville&id={R:1}"  />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it ! You have to use `&amp;` instead of `&`
Such an easy thing wasting so much time...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of trouble that I endlessly was able to fix by renaming the rule without spaces.

I had `<rule name="SPA Routes"...>` which throws a 500 and it was fixed after I renamed the rule to `<rule name="SPA"...>`